# Microsoft Azure - Where is my custom domain that I added using Azure AD portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have Azure subscription through Visual Studio Enterprise. Yesterday, using my `Azure AD Portal`, I added a custom domain `MyDomainName.com` - that I had bought from Google Domains. I had followed [this official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain) from MS Azure team. The domain was successfully created and verified per the instructions in the tutorial. But today when I login to Azure portal using the same Microsoft account that I use every day to login to Azure (and I also used to create the domain), and go to the left menu item `Custom Domain Names` of Azure AD page, I see only the default initial domain `MyMicorocoftAccount.onmicrosoft.com` that has always been there. But I don't see `MyDomainName.com`.

**Question**: How do I get access to `MyDomainName.com`?

**Remark**: I think one needs to be a user with proper permissions to the domain. But since I am the global admin to the entire Azure subscription and I am the one who added the custom domain, I am, by default, the global admin to the domain, as well. So how do I access the domain?

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the right directory? https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQ1njXP7tauxeufTv4ZzFqrFJ5Fw2B9cT7Pcw&usqp=CAU

Comment: If you have followed the procedure exactly as per the document it will be available in the custom domain option. Check whether you were looking into the correct directory.

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I'm new to Azure. Finding the directory was the issue. Response from User `@alphaz18` helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: @AlexAIT You are correct. Finding the correct directory was the issue. User `@alphaz18` helped me resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the top of the portal, next to the console button there is a directory and subscriptions button, click that, i suspect you have access/multiple directories and you created the custom domain in one of the other directories that you may have access to.

Because as mentioned by sruthi, if you added the domain properly/successfully, it will be there in that "custom domain names" blade.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). I'm new to Azure. You correctly understood what my issue could have been. I was struggling to find out where would be the directory that contains my `MyDomainName.com`. I had logged in to Azure Portal just as I had been doing everyday using Microsoft Account. But, as expected, it would take me to the default directory `MyHotmailAccount.onmicrosoft.com`. From there the search was not returning the tenant (directory) I had created for my domain. Your suggestion helped me find that directory.